# Rails Session :expire_after parameter on session_store prevents session from being stored

Tags: session, passenger, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In production and staging on engineyard / nginx / passenger / rails 4.1.5, upon submitting the login form, the user is found and authenticated but a session is not set with the user_id, therefore the app redirects back to sessions#new because there is no current_user.  On development, the login works properly.  It also works fine on digitalocean / nginx / puma / rails 4.0.3.  Changing the expired_after to 2.weeks still does not work.  But when I remove the :expire_after parameter, it works fine in production. We are confused by this problem.  What would prevent the session from being stored because of that parameter that works locally and in a different production environment? Thanks!

```
def create # Sessions_Controller
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to payments_url
  else
    flash[:now] = "Invalid combination of email and password. Please try again!"
    render 'new'
  end
end

# session_store
App::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', expire_after: 24.hours
```